# Python not exiting a function after it's done

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm trying to code a game for my comp-sci class. However, when I get to a function that dictates attacking an enemy even after the function completes it goes back to the top instead of continuing with the code. (Ignore the pointless for loop I just need one in my code) I have tried a bunch of stuff yet I still can't make it work at all.

```
lives = 3
primary = "Rusty Sword"
armor = "Old Armor"
damage = 2
luck = 3
defense = 1
defchance = 3
enemynumber = 0


print("\nYou begin your trek through the dense forest and you stumble accross a skeleton!\nThe skeleton has",enelives1,"lives.\nYou currently have",lives,"lives.")
print("\nInventory:\n"+primary+"-",damage,"Damage\n"+armor+"-",defense,"Defense")
aord = input("\nThe skeleton is coming towards you! Do you attack it or defend first?\n")
aord = aord.lower()
while aord != "attack" and aord != "defend": 
    print("Invalid input")
    print("Would you like to attack or defend?")
    aord = input("\nThe skeleton is coming towards you! Do you attack it or defend first?\n")

def attack1():
    hit = random.randint(1,luck)
    print("In order to attack the skeleton you must correctly guess a number from 1 to",luck+2,".")
    attackguess = int(input())
    guessnumber = 1
    global enelives1
    global lives
    while lives >= 3 and (guessnumber == 1 or guessnumber == 2):
        while guessnumber == 1:
            if attackguess > hit:
                print("Too high. One more chance.")
                guessnumber = 2
            elif attackguess < hit:
                print("Too low. One more chance.")
                guessnumber = 2
            else:
                enelives1 = enelives1 - damage
                print("You hit the skeleton! It now has",enelives1,"lives.")
                guessnumber = 3
            while guessnumber == 2:
                attackguess = int(input())
                if attackguess == hit:
                    enelives1 = enelives1 - damage
                    print("You hit the skeleton! It now has",enelives1,"lives.")
                    guessnumber = 3
                    global aord
                    aord == "defend"
        if lives >= 1 and guessnumber == 2:             
            print("You missed the skeleton! It is now about to swing at you!")
            aord = "defend"
        elif lives < 1:
            print("Oh no! You ran out of lives and died! Press enter to end the program")
            input()
            quit()



while enelives1 >= 1:            
    if aord == "attack":
        attack1()
    elif aord ==  "defend":
        defend1()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your function isn't exiting is because of the guessnumber while loops. If you're on your second guess, and you guess correctly, you will, as expected, enter the if statement for getting a hit and exit out. However, if you get second guess wrong, you become trapped in that while loop because guessnumber is still equal to 2. So the condition that keeps the while loop running is still true. To fix the not exiting, if they get the second guess wrong, you need to change the value of guessnumber (to anything but 1) like this:

```
while guessnumber == 2:
    attackguess = int(input())
    if attackguess == hit:
        enelives1 = enelives1 - damage
        print("You hit the skeleton! It now has" ,enelives1, "lives.")
        guessnumber = 3
        global aord
        aord == "defend"
    else: 
        guessnumber = 0 #this will allow while loop to break
```

Now if you change the value of the check, it should do ok:

```
if lives >= 1 and guessnumber == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really dug through your code to understand it but, at first glance, I'd think it has to do with the fact that you don't change the value of lives at all and yet exiting the while loop depends on lives being of a certain value.

Comment: It loops up to the beginning of the function again, which I know because after guessing the right number it goes back to the top of the function and prints the first print statement

Comment: It prints the "In order to attack..." statement?  Edit: I'm not getting how the exit conditions of that while loop can be satisfied.  It will go back to the top of the while loop because that's what while loops do when the exit condition isn't reached.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Ok so...I took more of a look at the while loop.  The exit condition is reached because if you hit, guessnumber becomes 3.  The lives part of the condition isn't doing anything right now.  Concerning the fact that it goes back to the top: it's going to go back to the top until you've done enough damage.  Am I missing something or did you already know that?  If you've done enough damage, the while loop should be exited.  You've tried to attack many times or just once?